# changing input value doesn't get reflected with firebug

Tags: jquery

Just trying to change the value of an input using jQuery.  Seems to work, however, when I look at the value of #input using Firebug, it remains at the original value.  Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong?  Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/tsfSg/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<title>Testing</title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script> 

$(function(){
    $("#DoIt").click(function()
    {
        $('#input').val('final');
        console.log($('#input'));
        alert($('#input').val());
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" id="DoIt">DoIt</a>
<input id="input" type="text" value="original" />
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.val()`: `console.log( $('#input').val() );`

```
$(function(){
    $("#DoIt").click(function(){
        $('#input').val('final');
        console.log($('#input').val());  // the fixed line!
        alert($('#input').val());
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tsfSg/1/)

---

**EDIT**

Now I understand at what you are looking: inside the element source (inspect element) in Firebug.
Well, if you want to see the change actually happen you'll have to use:

```
$('#input').attr('value','final');
```

instead of:

```
$('#input').val('final');
```

otherwise the change is stored by the browser (nothing to be afraid of) but not updated by Firebug.

```
in this demo you can see it working:
```

### *[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tsfSg/3/)*

```
$("#DoIt").click(function(e){
    $('#input').attr('value','final');     // use .attr() to see the change happen in Firebug!
    // $('#input').val('final');           //  but rather use this
    // $('#input').prop('value','final');  // or better THIS one!
    console.log( $('#input').val() );
    alert( $('#input').val() );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Roko.  Firebug still doesn't reflect the new value.  Is this normal?

Comment: @user1032531 Have you seen my example demo? open the console in Firebug: both alert and new console state are registered

Comment: Yes I did.  Maybe I am looking at the wrong thing.  When I look at the html tag in Firebug, it shows <input id="input" type="text" value="original"> both before and after DoIt is clicked.

Comment: @user1032531 Here, I finally understood at what you was looking. Now should work, but anyway use : `.prop()`!! Happy coding!